# use sed to make all comments consistent

Tags: file, text, sed

my file contains uneven comments:

```
// file1.php
        // Week 4 
        // Quiz
                               //coment3
//                     comment4
/ /comment5
      / /comment6
%comment7
%               comment8
                           %comment9
#comment10
#                     comment11
            #comment12
```

I want to make these comments consistent by replacing `#` or `//`  with just `//` followed by a single space.
I have: `s/[ \t]*//`.
it gives me

```
// file1.php
// Week 4 
// Quiz
//coment3
//                     comment4
/ /comment5
/ /comment6
#comment10
#                     comment11
#comment12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e 's,/[[:space:]]*/,//,' -e 's,[[:space:]]*//[[:space:]]*,// ,' -e 's/[[:space:]]*\([%#]\)[[:space:]]*/\1 /'
```